# how to get only data from responsetext

Tags: httpwebrequest, mootools, responsetext

i use mootools to get response from a webservice

```
  onSuccess: function (responseText) {
      alert(responsetext);
    }
```

as answer i get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<int xmlns="http://estimomini">15</int>
```

how do i get only the string  AKA 15 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the XML document will always look like this, try

```
onSuccess: function(responseText, responseXML) {
  alert(responseXML.documentElement.firstChild.data);
}
```

Comment: My responseXML is null though. I validated the output xml in the responseText and it looks fine. Do you know what could cause this? The content-type is text/xml

Comment: @IcedDante You should probably start a new question on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
     var req = new Request({
            url: 'data.xml',
            method: 'get',
            onSuccess: function(responseText, responseXML) {                
                var tempDiv = new Element('div', {html: responseText});
                var myInt = tempDiv.getElement('int').get('text');
                alert(myInt);
            }
        }).send();
});
</script>
```